# StreamWriter can't write in few folders(and no exception thrown) but it can write in different folder locations

Tags: c#, vb.net, streamwriter

StreamWriter can't write in few folders(and no exception thrown) but it can write in different folder locations. What is possible problem?

Comment: Please, provide some code and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Folder security issue, account I'm using doesn't have rights to write to that folder. So to write to it
1) Open Folder Property,
2) Navigate to 'Security' tab
3) Click 'Edit' and 'Add' in Newly opened tab
4) enter your pc name/... click 'Ok'

That should solve this issue. Thanks for your comments though :)

Comment: An exception was most likely thrown, but execution continued without breaking (this happens on some occasions, not really sure exactly what causes it). Did you check the _Immediate Window_?

Answer (score 1):

Some folder locations may require administrator rights, or you have some paths that even doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

File virtualization could be culprit of this behaviour. Since no exception is thrown, file is obviously successfully written, but probably to another folder as Windows sometimes redirects file writes to user-accessible folder. See [Common file and registry virtualization issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387), specifically Scenario 2.

Virtualization is Microsoft's way how not to break compatibility with older programs that relies on writing files to system folders (such as *Program Files*, *Windows*, etc.). Generally, you should avoid writing files to these folders as it is considered bad practise. Instead, write files under *Users* folder if possible.